# How can I deploy my solidity smart contract to ICP using Dfinity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, dfinity

I need to make a NFT marketplace which I implemented on Ethereum blockchain but need to do it in on ICP blockchain how can I do. Please share any references or projects.

I am new to ICP and doesn't know much about ICP and Dfinity